# How can I recognize the default project in Tableau?

Tags: java, rest, tableau-api

One of my unit tests is to delete all Tableau projects. All goes well until I encounter the default project which cannot be deleted. This would've been fair enough if I had a way to identify and skip it, but I don't.

I use Tableau server 10.5. When querying all projects this is what the default project looks like (server locale is German)

```
{  
"owner":{  
    "id":"56ecc1d6-3a57-4885-b612-17ed8609fbad"
},
"id":"dae54d6a-6fd3-11e8-b220-df8c1d2123b1",
"name":"Standard",
"description":"Das Standardprojekt, das von Tableau automatisch erstellt wurde.",
"createdAt":"2018-06-14T13:06:51Z",
"updatedAt":"2018-06-14T13:07:02Z",
"contentPermissions":"ManagedByOwner"
},
```

and this is what a normal project looks like:

```
{  
"owner":{  
    "id":"05d53bf4-206c-4afd-a02c-fc49902e4515"
},
"id":"8f2419a7-b648-4113-a43c-50b8d268f3bc",
"name":"Project Jeopardy",
"description":"project description",
"createdAt":"2018-07-02T17:02:54Z",
"updatedAt":"2018-07-02T17:02:54Z",
"contentPermissions":"ManagedByOwner"
},
```

The only thing is that the query returns an array and the default project so far has been first.

**Can I rely on the first project to be the default** when using no filters and default sort order? [The documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.5/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_Projects%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____64) does not clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [sort projects](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.5/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_concepts_filtering_and_sorting.htm) by creation date and the default project should then always be the first, except if someone resets the server clock for some reason.

This is good enough for my purposes but I will post another answer if I find a better solution.